# Bad performance on CiviEvent Dashboard

Tags: civievent, mysql, performance

We have a site that is fairly performant, around a second for most CiviCRM actions.

But the CiviEvent Dashboard is extremly slow, around 12 seconds. Over the years we have hosted a number of events with around 100 participants, but that should total no more than 1000-1500.

I can get Joomla (our CMS) to trace all queries, but that does not show CiviCRM database interaction, I think.

I'm looking for ideas, or pointers to documentation, on how to pin down the source of this irritating delay. It makes the whole Civi feel sluggish.

UPDATE: No other Dashbords or other CiviCRM menu entries are particularly slow. On a restored development site (exact copy of files and database) this delay does not exist. So this might be more of a network issue. Time To First Byte is 11,2 seconds on the live site. But I don't understand how one single menu entry can be so slow while others are not...

As there is no network activity during these 11 seconds I'm currently focusing on what Civi is doing during that time. Are there any logs that I can activate to pinpoint this?

Comment: Do you have the zoom extension? I've seen slowness before with events because it tries to contact zoom every time.

Comment: Make sure to deactivate the CiviMobile API extension before editing events from the events menu. CiviMobile API does severely slow down the loading process.

Comment: @Guitarman we do not have CiviMobile installed, but thanks, any ideas are welcome.

Comment: @demerit No using the Zoom extension either.